# Finding mode of numbers taken from an input file WITHOUT array

Tags: java

First, I have an input file with 11 (or less) lines of numbers.

Part of my assignment is to find the mode ( number that appears the most ) WITHOUT using arrays. I have tried to use for loops or if loops after finding the amount of lines in my input file. I know it sounds stupid to do this without arrays, but I am not allowed to use arrays in this assignment.

Since I made variables ( earnedGrade1, earnedGrade2, earnedGrade3, etc. ) for each number that is pulled from the input file, I'm not sure how to compare the numbers without using consecutive if statements ( as shown in example below ).

```
//Assume count has been declared and initialized to 0
//Assume earnedGrade1/2/3 has been intialized with the numbers 
pulled from input file

if(earnedGrade1 == earnedGrade2)
{
    count++;
}
if(earnedGrade1 == earnedGrade3)
{
    count++;
}
```

The above example doesn't seem to be a very good way to find the mode, since I would have to do around 11 if-statements for each and every earnedGrade variable.

If anyone has any suggestions, please do help.

Thank you for any help and please understand that I am new to programming.

Comment: @Aominè Um...like the math mode. The number that appears the most.

Comment: @FigletNewton I am not allowed to use arrays in this assignment. That's why I'm having problems with it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Are the numbers themselves sorted in the input file?

Comment: @FigletNewton Nope. They would be random doubles, such as...
100.00
86.52
77.52
85.61
etc...

Comment: This is better suited to a Map than an array.

Comment: @doelleri I'm not sure what a map is. I'm assuming it's something of slightly higher level, since I'm only taking an intro class.

Comment: How are you reading the file? And you are not allowed to read the file in to an array? That's a stupid requirement, if it's really the case.

Comment: @Aominè Well, so far I've learned if-statements, while loops, for loops, switch statements, method calling, pretty much only hit the basics.

Comment: @Radiodef Yes. Sadly, I'm not allowed to or this would make it much easier for me.I'm reading the file through a scanner.
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner("outputs.txt");

Comment: @Aominè Yea...it's just with how I was looking at it, I seem to have to make more than 100 if statements to do all of them...
So I was thinking there might be a simpler way.

Comment: Maps are much better than arrays for this, but I can see why that would be a problem.

Comment: There has got to be something you aren't telling us here.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without an array is to write a helper method, something like this:

```
static int count(double gradeToCount, double grade1, ..., double gradeN) {
    int count = 0;
    if (gradeToCount == grade1)
        count++;
    if (gradeToCount == grade2)
        count++;
    // And so on...
    return count;
}
```

It's just like if you were using a loop:

```
for (double grade : gradesArray)
    if (gradeToCount == grade)
        count++;
```

Except the loop is unrolled, and you check each grade and increment the count yourself.

Once you can count the occurrences of each grade, then you have to write another unrolled loop where you find the grade which has the maximum count.

Writing a helper method means that you only have to write out 2N comparisons by hand instead of N<sup>2</sup> comparisons.

I don't really know what you are supposed to learn from having to do it this way, except for why arrays are necessary I guess.

---

I was thinking about it again, and another way to do this would be to just repeatedly read the file using `Scanner`. Something like this:

```
Scanner in1 = new Scanner(fileOrPath);
while (in1.hasNextDouble()) {
    double gradeToCount = in1.nextDouble();

    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(fileOrPath);
    while (in2.hasNextDouble()) {
        double grade = in2.nextDouble();
        if (grade == gradeToCount)
            count++;
    }
}
```

This is pretty awful too, but it could be better than writing the comparisons by hand, I guess. I think Poosh's answer is suggesting something similar to this.

Comment: I see 3 options: 1. See how bad things are without arrays/primer to understand how arrays help. 2. Idea was for students to pick a different data type (like a map) 3. Teacher is a sadistic monster who likes to inflict pain on students - like my discrete mathematics teacher in uni ;-)

Comment: Hm...what would gradeToCount be? Would it be something like calling the method with the parameter as grade1, then next one would be grade2, etc.?

Comment: Yes, that's right. `int countOfGrade1 = count(grade1, grade1, grade2....; int countOfGrade2 = count(grade2, grade1, grade2.....;`

Comment: For your second one...wouldn't calling in a new scanner, end up with the first double being the same number as your gradeToCount double?

Sorry for the questions. I'm just getting into java and it's quite confusing for me.

Comment: Given that I picked up some sadistic tenancies from my discrete maths teacher I'm wondering if there is a Java8 1-liner that hides the use of arrays - i.e. read all the lines into a string, split it then use some Collectors to come up with the answer. That would impress your prof no end (but probably get you a fail because no one should know how to do it that way ;-)

Comment: @Amai Yeah, because when the grade to count finds itself, the count is 1. You will end up with duplicates. For example, say the grade 80.5 appears twice in the file. Then you'll end up counting 80.5 twice, but I don't think that's avoidable without having an array or a map to keep track of the numbers you've already seen. If you were allowed to use the map, you can find the mode in just one loop.

Comment: @John3136 This does the job: `StreamSupport.stream(((Iterable<String>) () -> new Scanner(filePath)).spliterator(), false).map(Double::valueOf).collect(groupingBy(d -> d, counting())).entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getKey()`. (Assuming a static import of `Collectors.*`.) Not sure if there's an easier way to turn the file in to a stream. ;p

Comment: I will look through this and try my best to use it in my program \o/

Comment: @Amai. if you are talking about the 1-liner I seriously wouldn't use it You will almost certainly find yourself in hot water for relying too much on "random internet sources". Whatever the point of the exercise is, the one liner completely misses it so you may be behind the 8 ball when you get to the next exercise. By all means study and understand, but handing it in as a solution is a being a smart alec - it uses arrays etc under the hood.

Comment: @John3136 Yes I understand that ~ I meant seeing what it does and trying to use that understanding to write up stuff ~

Comment: Yeah, my one-liner is terrible code. The `Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d, Collectors.counting())` part is the only part that's actually good. It just turns the `Stream<Double>` in to a frequency map `Map<Double, Long>`. I don't think I would actually do this with a stream in real code.

Comment: I would try to test the mode stuff but I cant even get my program past an InputMismatchException.x - x

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient, but here's an idea from what you mentioned you've covered in the course so far: read the input file into a String. Then write methods that let you do things to the String that you can do with an array, like get the count of items, and get the item at a certain index. Then you could do some loops using those methods.

One way might be to get the first number in the String, count how many times you find it, then store that number and how many times it appears in the String in variables. Then go to the second number in the String, do the same thing, and reset those variables if the number appears more times than the previous number. Otherwise leave the variables alone. Once you get to the last item in the String, you'll have your mode.

Another downside besides the inefficiency is that this would only find a single mode. You could overcome this by using another String to "play the role of an array" using methods.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest (yet most laborious) solution here would be to use several if-else statements like you suggest. I think your instructor wants to show you that using several if-else statements in programming is inefficient and that he is using this question in order to transition into another concept. Either that, or the instructor is simply making your assignment busy work by introducing this requirement.

Since you are in an introductory class you probably have not been taught about more advanced data structures like `ArrayList`s yet and so unless you are allowed to use such structures for this assignment, you will have no other option but to make a huge if-else section in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, I know it's a pain because the program need to loop through the file many times, but however, it may be helpful as it doesn't use any array nor Collection (*Explanation in Comments*):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * The "mode" is the value that occurs most often
 */
public class ModeWithoutArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count =0, lines = 0;
        double mode =0;
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Yahya\\Desktop\\grades.txt"); // for example
        try {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
            // count how many lines/grades the file contains
            while(read.hasNextLine()){
                read.nextLine();
                lines++;
            }

            // now compare every grade with the others (line by line) specified by the index "i"
            for(int i=0; i<lines; i++){
                int result = count(i, file); // count how many time it's repeated
                if(result>count){ // if it's bigger than the current count
                    count=result; // accept it
                    mode = findGrade(file, i); //then find the actual grade at that line                
                }
            }
            read.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(count>1){
           System.out.println("The Mode is: " + mode + ", Repeated " + count + " times" );
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No Mode Found" );
        }
    }

        // this method to count the repetition of a grade at particular line
        private static int count(int atLine, File file){

            double gardeToCount = 0;
            int count=0;

            try {
                Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
                // find the grade at that line
                gardeToCount = findGrade(file, atLine);

                // then compare it with other grades
                while(read.hasNextLine()){
                    if(gardeToCount==Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine())){
                        count++;
                    }           
                }

                read.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return count; // return the count
        }

        // this method to find the actual grade at a given line in the file
        private static double findGrade(File file, int atLine){
            int line =0;
            try {
                 Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
                 while(read.hasNextLine()){
                    if(line==atLine){
                        return Double.parseDouble(read.nextLine());
                    }
                    read.nextLine();
                    line++;
                }
                 read.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return 0;
        }   
}
```

**Test**

*The File Content (grades.txt)*

```
50
60
70
80
50
60
60
90
100
```

*Output*

```
The Mode is: 60.0, Repeated 3 times
```

**UPDATE**

Another approach, which is also more efficient, instead of reading the file many times ***[Also Added Validation To The File Content]***, you can do something like this (*Explanation in Comments*):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * The "mode" is the value that occurs most often
 */
public class ModeWithoutArray {
    static int count =0, lines = 0;
    static double mode =0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // the file that contains the grades (a grade at each line)
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Yahya\\Desktop\\grades.txt");

        // get all grades and convert them to a String separated by one space
        String allGrades = collectGrades(file); 

        double gradeToComapre = 0;
        int gradeRep = 0;

        // compare every grade with the others and count its repetition
        // every round change mode and count to the bigger values
        for(int i=1; i<=lines; i++){
            gradeToComapre = grade(allGrades, i);
            for(int j=i; j<=lines; j++){
                if(gradeToComapre==grade(allGrades, j)){
                    gradeRep++;
                }
            }
            if(gradeRep>count){
                count=gradeRep;
                mode = gradeToComapre;
            }
            gradeRep = 0;
        }


        if(count>1){ // if there is a mode
           System.out.println("The Mode is: " + mode + ", Repeated " + count + " times." );
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The Collection Has No Mode!" );
        }

    }



        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        /**
         * This method to collect all Valid Grades 
         * from a given file and concatenate them to a String to be
         * returned at the end
         * @param file
         */
        private static String collectGrades(File file){
            String allGrades = "";
            try {
                Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
                // read the file and accept ONLY valid grades 
                while(read.hasNextLine()){
                    String oneGrade = read.nextLine().trim();
                    if(!oneGrade.isEmpty() && isValidGrade(oneGrade)){
                        allGrades += oneGrade + " "; // one space between every grade
                        // increment the global variable lines 
                        // to be used in the comparison loops
                        lines++; 
                    }
                }
                read.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 System.out.println("File Does Not Exists!");
                 System.exit(0);
            }

            return allGrades;   
        }


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        /**
         * This method to check if a given Grade is valid
         * this will return true/false
         * @param oneGrade
         */
        private static boolean isValidGrade(String oneGrade){
            try{ // try to parse it as a double value
                // this will throw an exception if it's not a number!
                double theGrade = Double.parseDouble(oneGrade);
                if(theGrade>=0 && theGrade<=100){ // is it in the range?
                    return true;
                }
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                // catch the exception if it's not a number
                // and return false
                return false;
            }
            // return false if it's <0 or >100
            return false;
        }



        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        /**
         * This method to fetch a particular grade from the
         * String that contains all grades
         * @param allGrades
         * @param index
         */
        private static double grade(String allGrades, int index){
            String oneGrade = "";
            int count = 0;
            for(char c : allGrades.toCharArray()){
                if(!Character.isWhitespace(c)){
                    // if it's not a space, concatenate the char to oneGrade
                    oneGrade += c;
                }
                else{ // the space determines the end of grade
                    count++;
                    if(count==index){ // if it's the required grade
                        // return it as a double
                        return Double.parseDouble(oneGrade);
                    }
                    else{// if it's not the required grade
                        // restart concatenation
                        oneGrade = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            // this will never be the case unless you 
            // ask for a grade out the range 
            // (e.g. there are 3 grades and you want the fourth!!)
            return -1;
        }

}
```

**Test**

*The File Content (grades.txt)*

```
50
60.5
66
75
32
95
50.5
75
60.5
80
60.5
78
```

*Output:*

```
The Mode is: 60.5, Repeated 3 times.
```